# Prefixing interfaces with I?

Tags: unit-testing, interface, dependency-injection, tdd, coding-style

I am currently reading "Clean Code" By Rober Martin (UncleBob), and generally loving the musings of UncleBob. However, I got a bit confused, when I read that he avoids prefixing interfaces like "IPerson". He states "I don't want my users knowing that I'm handing them an interface".

Thinking in TDD/injection perspective, I will always be very interested in telling the "users" of my classes that I am handing on an interface. The primary reason is that I consider Interfaces contracts between the different "agents" of a system. An agent working with one corner of my system, should not know the concrete implementation of another agents work; they should only exchange contracts, and expect the contracts to be fulfilled without knowing how. The other, but also very important, reason is that an interface can be mocked fully, and thus making unit-testing much easier. There are limits to how much you can mock on a concrete class.

Therefore, I prefer to visualize that I am indeed handing on an interface... or taking an interface as argument. But since UncleBob is a heavyweight champ in our community, and I am just another flyweigth desk jockey, I would like to know if I am missing something.

Is it wrong for me to insist on I's in interfaces??

Comment: I think this is a matter of preference. Although, in most languages it's a convention to prefix an interface with an I.

Comment: @Kevin Most languages?

Comment: @Cumbayah Should've probably been a bit more precise. With __most__ I actually meant: Java, C# and VB.NET.

Comment: @Kevin Actually, the standard in Java's class libraries is to not prefix interfaces (instead suffixing Impl on concrete classes when necessary).

Comment: @Cumbayah Oh, books like Head First design patterns and such thought me otherwise. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @Kevin, @Cumbayah: The I-Prefix convention originated with Microsoft's COM in C++ and was adoped very widely. That explains why it got some traction in Java despite not being in Sun's code conventions (which are otherwise followed by most Java programmers), and why it's the official convention for .Net

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: Great stuff!

Comment: Just upvoting everything here, because all points are very valuable!!! Thanks

Comment: Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117348/should-interface-names-begin-with-an-i-prefix and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329098/naming-issues-should-isomething-be-renamed-to-something

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There are a number of conventions in Java and C# that we have grown comfortable with; but that are backwards. For example, the convention of putting private variables at the top of each class is quite silly from a technical point of view. The most important things about a class are its public methods.  The *least* important things, the things we *hide* behind a privacy barrier, are the instance variables. So why would we put them at the top?

The "I" in front of interfaces is another backwards convention. When you are passed a reference to an object, you should *expect* it to be an interface. Interfaces should be the default; so there is no point in doing something extra, like using an I prefix, to announce that you are doing what everyone expects you to do. It would be better (though still wrong) if we reserved a special marker for the *exceptional* condition of passing a concrete class.

Another problem with using I, is that (oddly) we use it to communicate the *implementation decision* of using an interface.  Usually we don't want implementation decisions expressed so loudly, because that makes them hard to change.  Consider, for example, what might happen if you decided that IFoo really ought to be an abstract class instead of an interface.  Should you change the name to Foo or CFoo, or ACFoo?

I can hear the wheels turning in your head.  You are thinking: "Yeah, but interfaces have a special place in the language, and so it's reasonable to mark them with a special naming convention."  That's true.  But integers also have a special place in the language, and we don't mark them (any more).  Besides, ask yourself this: *why* do interfaces have a special place in the language?

The whole idea behind interfaces in Java and C# was a cop-out.  The language designers *could* have just used abstract classes, but they were worried about the difficulties of implementing multiple inheritance.  So they made a back-room deal with themselves.  They invented an artificial construct (i.e. interfaces) that would provide *some* of the power of multiple inheritance, and they constrained normal classes to single inheritance.

This was one of the worst decision the language designers made.  They invented a new and heavyweight syntax element in order to *exclude* a useful and powerful (albeit controversial) language feature.  Interfaces were not invented to enable, they were invented to *disable*.  Interfaces are a hack placed in the language by designers who didn't want to solve the harder problem of MI. So when you use the I prefix, you are putting a big spotlight on one of the largest hacks in language history.

The next time you write a function signature like this:

```
public void myFunction(IFoo foo) {...}
```

Ask yourself this:  "Why do I want to know that the author of IFoo used the word 'interface'?  What difference does it make to me whether he used 'interface' or 'class' or even 'struct'?  *That's his business, not mine!*  So why is he forcing me to know his business by putting this great big I in front of his type name?  Why doesn't he zip his declarations up and keep his privates out of my face?"

Comment: I hear You!! Your points and the points from the others is slowly beginning to effect my brain waves. I have also wondered how come I haven't let go on the I's when I let go of the int's and the dbl's and the flt's years ago.

Comment: Although I 100% agree on that using 'I' is totally unnecessary, I can't imagine myself dropping this habit anytime soon. I couldn't say why, but I like to name interfaces like that.

Comment: Wow, how the mighty have fallen... I remember back in neolithic times when I was a PhD student and the world was young, all the PL Profs were very proud of this new Interface features that "solved" multiple inheritance, now they are just a "hack"... I can only think of Stroustrup saying to them: "I told you so"...

Comment: This Q&A is ancient and off-topic on SO, but I can't believe no one said that interfaces are not just a cop-out. They are an acceptable compromise to a generally unsolvable problem of multiple inheritance, which requires trade-offs whichever way you put it. IMO they should've been allowed to have anything but fields (which is now in C#8), but I highly respect the design attitude of making good practices built into the language (stateless abstract classes) and downright banning questionable confusing features with good alternatives (stateful multi-inheritance vs composition).

Comment: When you know that it is an interface you understand that you can pass Foo1, Foo2 and even FooooF, but when it's a class or struct you can only pass Foo, so you should know the business of the author in order to work with his code, I can't take this as a serious argument.

Comment: @TamimAttafi "you can only pass Foo" Not true. A Foo parameter will happily accept anything that derives from Foo, besides Foo itself.

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi I agree, but you have to specify that your class is open or abstract in order to make the consumer aware about that. Using an interface makes it clear from the first glance, adding "I" to the name will make it even more helpful and will economize the time spent to know the nature of the parameter's type. Struct is usually final and doesn't accept inheritance, that what I've seen in my experience with Swift and Kotlin's data class. Maybe in C++ it is, but in modern languages structs are usually final cuz they are used for storing data, and should not share logic.

Comment: I wonder if the author of this answer ever worked at a large company and found himself in a situation where he needed to fix code he didn't write.  In this case it is absolutely my business what the other developer used and why.

Having worked professionally in Java and C# (and C++), I miss the clear indication that I am looking at an interface that the 'I' gave me.  It's a very clear indication I need to look deeper.  

Comparing the 'I' prefix to Hungarian notation isn't exactly apples to apples:  one tells you a data type, the other hints at design decisions.

Comment: @mlindegarde, good points. I also feel like this answer makes a lot of open ended statements. Why would I use an abstract class for example when I want the features of an interface? Was this answer written just to have a place to nitpick at language decisions?

Comment: Tell you why the private members are opening the class:
1. this is why it called "convention" - to form classes in a way that the whole system will be uniformed 
2. in avg class you have 5-10 members top, you don't need to actually "scroll" from this point. its 10 lines TOP
3. public functions in class are many, you WILL NEED to scroll throughout the functions no matter with or without privates

Answer (score 14):

> I consider Interfaces contracts
>   between the different "agents" of a
>   system. An agent working with one
>   corner of my system, should not know
>   the concrete implementation of another
>   agents work; they should only exchange
>   contracts, and expect the contracts to
>   be fulfilled without knowing how. The
>   other, but also very important, reason
>   is that an interface can be mocked
>   fully, and thus making unit-testing
>   much easier. There are limits to how
>   much you can mock on a concrete class.

All of this is true - but how does it necessitate a naming convention for interfaces?

Basically, prefixing interfaces with "I" is nothing but another example of the useless kind of Hungarian notation, because in a statically typed language (the only kind where interfaces as a language construct make sense) you can always easily and quickly find out what a type is, usually by hovering the mouse over it in the IDE.

Comment: Amen. Claiming the I-prefix helps me understand the code is like claiming that the sentence "nounI verbAm properCumbayah" is easier to understand. Programming is, in essense, about creating a language for addressing the problem domain, and those kind of implementation level clutter adds nothing of value to to that language. When we do need to see such low level details, our tools are perfectly capable of showing them.

Comment: I know that I can easily find out what a type is. But hovering over a type, to find out what I am dealing with, is not doing much for readability which is another (even more??) important point in Clean Code. Confronted with an I-prefixed type, I instinctively know that: A) The possibility that any number of implementations of this interface exists, B) Other agents of the system might be using this interface, C) For test purposes, I can stub/mock this contract, so i can Induce certain behaviour. All this I get from a tiny letter. Maybe it is wrong to put so much meaning into I's??

Comment: @Morten: Actually, I'd say that keeping technical matters out of names is the best thing you can do for readability. And your ABC points are all technical implementation details that client code should not care about.

Comment: @Cumbayah, Hi there... hope things are ok at your end :o) Are you saying that the prefix is redundant(Then I have a lot of renaming of YOUR old interfaces to do hehe)? It suddenly appears to me, that maybe I should always EXPECT interfaces to be passed rather than concrete classes. Given that assumption, I can see why the prefixed could be omitted.

Comment: Well said(+1)... Though: " in a statically typed language (the only kind where interfaces as a language construct make sense)" This being the internet, I imagine the readers will come up with examples where interfaces make sense in a dynamically typed language like python as well ;)

Comment: "you can always easily and quickly find out what a type is, usually by hovering the mouse over it in the IDE."

Who uses a mouse when they code?

Comment: exactly, interfaces don't need an I prefix to mark that they are are prefix because they already have a marker 'interface'. That the type is declared with 'interface' instead of 'class' tells you that it is an interface. Any modern IDE will highlight class and interfaces differently.

Answer (score 12):

If you're talking about .NET, then interfaces with `I` at the beginning are so ubiquitous that dropping them would confuse the hell out of everyone.

Plus I'd much rather have

```
public class Foo : IFoo {}
```

than

```
public class FooImpl : Foo {}
```

It all boils down to personal preference and I did for a while play with the idea myself but I went back to the `I` prefix. YMMV

Comment: I agree that sufix `Impl` is awful, but you can use something else. Eg.: I prefer `class SystemClock : Clock` over `class Clock : IClock`. Or even `class DefaultClock : Clock`. And yes, i don't like the `I` suffix.

Comment: But what when you have one implementation for your interface (Dependency inversion), which shouldn't be named neither SystemClock nor DefaultClock, only can be named Clock, how to handle this? For example, UserRepository : IUserRepository

Comment: If you have to put the I in front of Foo to describe an interface is because you're missing the abstraction. interface Animal { }, class Dog implements Animal { }. It is not a matter of taste, it is a matter of not applying abstraction correctly.

Comment: @TamimAttafi Same applies. Your UserRepository is probably an UserDbRepository. You may use multiple kinds of storage and your UserRepository interface isn't aware of that. Interfaces should have abstract names while classes should be specific.

Comment: "...Impl" is awful. Maybe FooDto or FooModel could be some implementation of the Foo data interface?

Answer (score 0):

Onestly, after some deep thought, I'm convinced that God invented the "I" to claim that an object can do that thing. I mean, to me it is clearly a way for some object to express that it can do that thing (but i'm not a native English speaker).

Let's say that I have an interface "IDoSomething", it should have a methond "doSomething" because it claims that *it does something* in its interface, so the "I" as prefix for interfaces is not because it is an interface, but because the object that implements the interface is saying "*I* (can) do something"

Anyway the accepted answer is from Mr Clean Code and I think he knows best.

But I also think that my theory has some good point anyway.

Comment: That argument only applies if the interface is verb-y. `IPerson` would be redundant; a `Person` is a person.

Comment: Interesting! well you could also use the "Im" prefix on pojo interfaces like that! Person/IPerson would be ImPerson! (ImJoking haha)