# What are the correct class/interface names for a publish/subscribe pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, coding-style, naming-conventions

I have this interface to let someone listen to a certain event

```
interface XXX
{
    void subscribe( string event, func callback );
    void unsubscribe( string event, func callback );
}
```

Also, I have another interface which provides a way to 'publish' an event.

```
interface YYY
{
    void publish( string event, params[] params );
}
```

Then, I have a class which implements both interfaces. It acts as a 'broadcast station" where people can subscribe to some events and also publish things on it so everyone connected will get the event

```
class ZZZ: XXX, YYY
{

    void subscribe( string event, func callback )...
    void unsubscribe( string event, func callback )...
    void publish( string event, params[] params )...
}
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out what should be the correct names for these classes/interfaces. Currently I'm using IEventBroadcaster for the subscription/unsubscription, IEventPublisher for the publish part and BroadcastStation for the class the implements both.

I wonder if there are some kind of standard naming for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking in SO is starting to be a little bit annoying. It's not that I'm not getting answers, it's more like I'm not getting views which is far worse. Where are the people?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with IPublisher and ISubscriber ? Or maybe if you want "slick", ability indicating interfaces, IPublishEvents and ISubscribeToEvents ?

As for the class implementing this interfaces the name should describe the purpose of that class  - assuming that the class has a purpose other than just publishing and subscribing to events.

Comment: Don't prefix interfaces with an 'I'. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816951/prefixing-interfaces-with-i

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion on this, but you can [find arguments](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/11/09/the-last-vestiges-of-hungarian-notation/) for both sides. I think what's important is to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for an Observer [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):
[image]

So you can use classig register/unregister/notify names.