# Doesn't avoiding the initial I for interfaces in TypeScript lead to naming conflicts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

In most of the TypeScript code I've seen so far people decided against the pattern of prefixing interfaces with `I` (as is done in C#, e.g.). I understand the reasoning behind that, e.g. that this way interfaces follow the same naming schema as types or classes do. So far, so good.

But won't this lead to naming issues in the long run, for example if a default implementation of an interface is given, too?

Suppose you have an interface called

```
ICustomer
```

and a class

```
Customer implements ICustomer
```

then it is pretty clear which is what. You can tell the interface from the class by just looking at their names. Now I assume that the usual way to do this in TypeScript is to name the interface `Customer`. But then I have to rename my class to something else, such as `DefaultCustomer` or something like that, which is unneeded from the POV of the class.

How do you deal with that?

(I hope that there is a technical reason why this isn't a problem, or a common best practice on how to solve this, and that it's not "primarily opinion-based".)

Comment: Class and interface both r types and two types can not hv same name in any typed language. That's the reason we prefix interface with "I"  in most typed language viz, c#, TS etc.

Comment: I think this is mostly opinion based. The only technical reason is that in TS it is common to have an interface that is not implemented explicitly by a class. Interfaces are commonly used to describe the shape of objects created from object literals for example and as such require no class implementing them and thus no conflict.

Comment: You will find that in Typescript interfaces are not used as contracts for classes. Instead they are mostly used as lightweight types (types without classes, eg. React props) and sometimes higher-order polymorphic types (kinds). For the first use there is no conflict because you will never need to define class Customer for interface Customer (it would just be an object literal as Customer). For the second case naming your kind the same as your type is an anti-pattern...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you're worried about, when you're deciding to refuse `I` prefix, is: "I don't want to name my classes like `class CustomerImpl implements Customer`". But in TypeScript, because of [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface), you usually use an Interface without a class implementation at all, for example:

```js
const customer: Customer = {
  name: "Foo",
  age: 123
};
```

I've written a ton of TypeScript code, and I never faced naming conflicts. Usually, interfaces describe only shape of the object, and doesn't require an implementation, like example above.

In general, you create classes, when the interface (or abstract class) requires multiple implementations, like `MockCustomer`, `RichCustomer`. In this case you have general interface name 'Customer', and exact implementation names.

If an interface requires only single class implementation, why to create the interface? You can use the class directly. Maybe single class implementation makes sense for a library, when you don't want to expose your implementation. But, in case of library, I rather prefer to use third party names like "Customer" than "ICustomer".

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5816951/4858777) another post about using `I` prefix in general, may be it would be helpful too.

Comment: I am usually using interfaces over classes when the class does not provide any logic besides simple getter/setter so a plain (typed) object suffices. If any sort of logic is necessary I switch to an instantiated class.

Comment: Lets say you have a type `CartItem` and a `CartItem` component which takes a `CartItem` as `props`, do I now use a `I` prefix or a `Type` suffix for the `CartItem` type or like you suggest nothing and have a naming conflict?